# Apache2.4 mod_wsgi error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: django, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
I create a django project under /opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash
and create a wsgi file cash.wsgi in the same directory

**Here is the content of cash.wsgi**

```
 import os
 import sys

 path = '/opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/'
 sys.path.insert(0, path)
 from cash import settings
 import django.core.management
 sys.path.insert(1, '/opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash/')
 django.core.management.setup_environ(settings)
 utility = django.core.management.ManagementUtility()
 command = utility.fetch_command('runserver')
 command.validate()
 import django.conf
 import django.utils
 django.utils.translation.activate(django.conf.settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
 import django.core.handlers.wsgi
 application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**and here is what I add to my httpd.conf:**

```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.abcd.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:+MEDIUM:!SSLv2:!EXP:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL
    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/certs/www.abcd.org.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/ssl/www.abcd.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/certs/DigiCertCA.crt"
    #SSLCertificateChainFile "/opt/ssl/IntermediatesCA3.crt"
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    Alias /media-cash/ /opt/cashpro/cashfiles
   <Directory /opt/cashpro/cashfiles>
           Options MultiViews
           AllowOverride None
           Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias /site 
   /opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash/cash.wsgi
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/serror.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/saccess.log common
   </VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, when I visit https://www.abcd.org/site, it says

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache Error log

```
[Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.263573 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340] mod_wsgi (pid=4448): Target WSGI script 
 '/opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash/cash.wsgi' cannot be loaded as 
 Python module., referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.263816 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340] mod_wsgi (pid=4448): Exception occurred 
 processing WSGI script 
 '/opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash/cash.wsgi'., referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.263978 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264085 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File 
 "/opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash/cash.wsgi", line 11, in 
 <module>, referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264223 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     command = 
 utility.fetch_command('runserver'), referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264261 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command, 
 referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264325 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     klass = load_command_class(app_name, 
 subcommand), referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264360 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in 
 load_command_class, referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264410 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     module = 
 import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name)), referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264452 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module, referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264495 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     __import__(name), referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264524 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 8, in <module>, 
 referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264570 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     from django.core.servers.basehttp import 
 AdminMediaHandler, run, WSGIServerException, get_internal_wsgi_application, 
 referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264599 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 26, in <module>, referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264637 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     from django.views import static, referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264665 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/views/static.py", line 95, in <module>, referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264700 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     template_translatable = 
 ugettext_noop(u"Index of %(directory)s"), referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264727 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 75, in gettext_noop, 
 referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264780 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     return _trans.gettext_noop(message), 
 referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264821 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__, 
 referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264852 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     if settings.USE_I18N:, referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264879 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner, referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264912 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     self._setup(), referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264938 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup, referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.264987 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module), 
 referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.265015 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
 packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 135, in __init__, referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.265044 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     logging_config_func(self.LOGGING), 
 referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.265071 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", 
 line 794, in dictConfig, referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.265116 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] [ 
 client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     dictConfigClass(config).configure(), 
 referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.265151 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", 
 line 576, in configure, referer: https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.265201 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340]     '%r: %s' % (name, e)), referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
 [Thu Jul 20 22:24:56.265284 2017] [:error] [pid 4448:tid 140570219427584] 
 [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3340] ValueError: Unable to configure handler 
 'default': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/cash_site.log', referer: 
 https://www.abcd.org
```

Another python web app host the same server.But getting error

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName www.xyz.com
 ServerAlias xyz.com
 DocumentRoot /opt/nadasnapp/html
 <Directory /opt/nadasnapp/html/>
    Require all granted
 AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
  LogLevel warn
 ##FOR NADA
 Alias /media/ /opt/nadasnapp/python_app/NaDaWebPro/media/
    <Directory /opt/nadasnapp/python_app/NaDaWebPro/media/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    Alias /static/ /opt/nadasnapp/python_app/NaDaWebPro/static_root/
    <Directory /opt/nadasnapp/python_app/NaDaWebPro/static_root/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    #FOR NADA
  WSGIPassAuthorization On
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/nadasnapp/python_app/NaDaWebPro/nada/wsgi.py
  <Directory /opt/nadasnapp/python_app/NaDaWebPro/nada>
  <Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
  </Files>
  </Directory> 
   </VirtualHost>
```

The error is

```
 [Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.151745 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 
139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244] mod_wsgi (pid=4594): Exception occurred 
processing WSGI script 
 '/opt/nadasnapp/python_app/NaDaWebPro/nada/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.151993 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152065 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152135 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]     self.load_middleware()
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152166 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
 [Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152203 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 1 
39820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]     for middleware_path in 
settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152234 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152319 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]     self._setup()
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152357 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152402 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]     self._wrapped = 
Settings(settings_module)
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152445 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152484 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244]     raise ImportError("Could not import 
settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Sun Jul 23 04:23:14.152540 2017] [:error] [pid 4594:tid 139820915422976] 
[client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2244] ImportError: Could not import settings 
'cash.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named cash.settings
```

Comment: Is the directory `/opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/` owned by `apache` or does the `apache` user have enough permissions to access it?

Comment: @jgmh its only have root ownership.

Comment: Remember that `apache` or whatever user defined in httpd.conf requires permissions to the dir.  Try changing the ownership of that dir with `chown -R apache:apache /opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/`

Comment: @jgmh changed the ownership as you told.but issue not solved.

Comment: Did you restart / reload apache service?

Comment: @jgmh yes.I restart the apache service.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should really use mod_wsgi daemon mode. There is rarely a good reason to use embedded mode, even if it is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory you gave as argument to the `Directory` directive was `/opt/cashpro/cashfiles`, it should be `/opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash/`. That is, where the WSGI script file is located.

Comment: I got an error like this

  mod_wsgi (pid=4448): Target WSGI script 
 '/opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash/cash.wsgi' cannot be 
  loaded as Python module.
 ] mod_wsgi (pid=4448): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 
 '/opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash/cash.wsgi'

Comment: There should have been some sort of Python exception and traceback after that. What was it? It will tell you what is wrong in your code. At a guess you haven't told mod_wsgi about your Python virtual environment. Ensure you are using daemon mode but more importantly go read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Its working me when run  
python /opt/cashpro/python_app/cashsite/trunk/cash/manage.py  runserver 0.0.0.0:8000.

Comment: As I said above, there should be more in the Apache error log than what you gave. What else was there after that line?

Comment: Please check error log on my question.I have updated.

Comment: Read both http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user and http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory Your code runs as Apache user by default not as root and not as you. It needs write access to directories. You also can't use relative path names to files because the current working directory is undefined.

Comment: You should also configure logging to log to terminal (stdout/stderr). Messages will then appear in Apache error log. Usually no point having logging module use a separate log file when using Apache.

Comment: At the same server, i have host another Python web app, the configuration is

Comment: At the same server, I have host another Python web app, the configuration is added above.Please look up

Comment: Read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user Your code run as Apache user and will not have access to directories. Make sure you use daemon mode and look at running daemon mode processes as specific user that does have access.

Comment: @ Graham Dumpleton, that's working, I agree, This is new Python web app and separates virtual host config.please look up abode updated config file and error

Comment: @ Graham Dumpleton, when I give www-data ownership to /opt/nadasnapp/python_app/NaDaWebPro/nada/ this path, now my old web-app www.abcd.org get internal server error.

Comment: If you are running two Django web sites, make sure you are using daemon mode and that each is running in a separate daemon process group, else they can interfere with each other. Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html There is usually not good reason to run embedded mode, especially if you don't understand the difference.

Comment: @ Graham Dumpleton, 
I have added some values like this on my virtual-host configuration.But getting same error WSGIDaemonProcess pydaemon-3 processes=1 threads=5 <Location /> WSGIProcessGroup pydaemon-3 WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} </Location>

Comment: But have you told mod_wsgi where your project is located using the ``python-path`` option. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/